# Non-OP unaccept?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

It is not at all an infrequent occurrence that I run across a question with a quick answer, quickly accepted, that is demonstrably wrong. Not just not as good as it might be, but actually harmful to anyone seeking answers to the question posed.

Since the OP was presumably asking the question because his knowledge of the subject is limited, why do we trust only him to be the judge of the best answer?

There should be a way for the rest of us to perhaps vote to close an answer or unapprove an answer just like we vote on questions. Also, it might not be a bad idea for a newbie OP to be required to either wait some period of time or for some minimal number of answers before being allowed to accept.

For a concrete example: [Is it possible to peek at the next rand value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528489/is-it-possible-to-peek-at-the-next-rand-value)

Comment: Just downvote it. Upvotes and downvotes are how we judge answers. An accept is just the view of one person.

Comment: @RobertLongson yet it pins the post to the top

Comment: That is a bad example. Regardless of the flaws in the answer, the OP stated it was exactly what he was after. Therefore *in his opinion* it is the correct answer. You and I don't have to like it.

Comment: You are 100% mistaken. Given answer absolutely did not do what OP asks, and in fact totally eliminates the RNG's ability to produce random numbers. If--and only if--the RNG happens to be an old-fashioned LCG, it will appear to behave as the OP wants, but that just makes the answer even worse.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that would be up to the OP to decide, not you

Comment: Why do you assume the OP is competent? He is asking, after all. If he knew what a right answer looked like, he wouldn't have to ask.

Comment: That is true, @LeeDanielCrocker, but it is the OP's choice, for better or worse. Demanding they change the answer they chose won't necessarily work - put as much detail, explanation and justification in your answer - that is more likely to convince them than nagging and pestering.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Why do you assume you're able to read the poster's mind to know what specifically **they** wanted? The OP knows exactly what they're trying to accomplish, and they know *exactly* which answer *solved the problem to their satisfaction*. You're asking for us to decide which of the several slices of pie **you're** eating is best tasting, ignoring what **you** think of the taste. SO was designed to work exactly the way it is with regard to accepting answers - the only person who can decide which answer is the accepted solution is the person who asked the question.

Comment: The question isn't just for the OP. It's also for all the people who will search for it, find it, and find an answer that absolutely, 100%, does not answer the question as written, even if it might happen to be what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: All of this misunderstanding rises from the fact that you believe *an accepted answer is supposed to be correct.* Which isn't true. As clearly stated in the comments above, *accepting an answer means that it worked for the OP of the question, nothing more.* See the picture? If the answer's wrong, downvote and comment. This is how the system works.

Comment: You may be right, but I think my perception is also the perception of 99% of users. And still, I have seen no attempt to answer the question: WHY is the present system the way it is, and why would changing it be bad?

Answer (score 3):

Asking a question gives you a special privilege: the privilege to determine what answer helped you best. That special vote gives a bonus of 15 reputation point. No one else has anything to do with that vote, just like no one can tell you if you should up-vote or down-vote. The OP can determine best which answer helped him / her most.

The thing we *can* argue about is the order of the answers. In my opinion, the highest scoring answer *could* be on top instead of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is essentially "accepting an answer invalidates the rest in the eyes of all readers". I think this premise is fundamentally incorrect.

Here's part of a response I wrote to a [different question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287650/how-to-partially-answer-my-own-question-protocol/287651#287651), that I think is relevant here:

> An answer not being accepted doesn't mean it's "wrong", it just means it's *probably* not the one that answers the question the best. Upvotes and downvotes effectively rate other non-accepted answers, as well as the accepted one, and readers are both free to and capable of looking at the votes and reading other answers as well. So don't think that accepting one answer somehow invalidates the rest.

In other words, if the answer with the green check mark next to it isn't correct, the votes will eventually reflect that. A reader will either try the accepted answer, realize it's incorrect, then move to the next one, or just ignore it and go straight to the higher voted answer. What would *you* do if you were looking for a solution and saw an incorrect accepted answer? You'd probably skip it and find a correct one, I assume. Well, as it turns out, other readers have the same powers that you do.

Even if the OP accepted an incorrect answer, eventually they *will* realize it didn't solve their problem. Maybe they won't come back to the site to change the check mark but I'm not sure that really matters because, again, readers are humans just like you who are capable of filtering information, and (at least in my experience) the types of questions that I see incorrect accepted answers on tend to not be the most useful questions anyways.

And yes, every once in a while, an accepted answer is blatantly incorrect. The options you *do* have are:

- Leave a comment warning other readers.
- Downvote it.
- Post a better answer.
- Deal with it.

---

As for your *specific* example; the accepted answer helped the OP solve their problem. End of story. Maybe all they needed was a reminder that `srand()` exists and didn't actually need the entire thing written for them. Maybe they'll come back tomorrow and change the accepted answer (the question was only asked yesterday, perhaps they didn't notice a different answer yet). Who knows? It's not up to us to decide which answer the OP gets to place their check mark by.

But if you have a similar question you are perfectly able to look at the different answers there and choose the one that fits your particular situation the best. Maybe a reader comes and isn't trying to peek at the next N random numbers, and the accepted answer is exactly what they need. Maybe a reader comes and just missed an obvious approach, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30528735/616460) is all they need. People will figure out what answer is useful for them.

Comment: *Deal with it* is maybe the least understood and most overlooked option...

Comment: And the least useful. If you can't give a good reason for *why* the current system is the way it is, then just maybe there isn't one.

Comment: @Lee Your unwillingness to accept the fact that we choose to give the OP of a question the power to determine on their own what they find helpful does not equate to a failure of the system. Their choice is not yours to make, even if you disagree. The underlying theme in everything you have said here is that you do not seem to have faith in the ability of others to make the same types of decisions that you can. Also I suspect this originated with one of your own answers not being accepted. In any case, you should reflect on why this bothers you. The other options presented are good as well.

Comment: I'm not "unwilling to accept" anything. I'm just waiting to hear a good argument for it. I've heard nothing but "That's the way it is."  If it really is better the way it is, it shouldn't be hard to come up at it a reason. If the reason is good, I'll be all for it.

Comment: If nobody can come up with a reason for it, why not just eliminate the "accepted" answer idea entirely, and just let votes speak?

Comment: @Lee If you can present a concrete analysis of the current system and a case for removing the concept of "accept", you should create a new meta post. I'm sure it will be an interesting discussion. Search meta and the help center for existing related discussion and info first if you do.

Comment: (@Lee You might also want to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work first for some insight into the current purpose. The reason nobody is giving you reasons here is because information is already easy enough to find, repeating it is unnecessary. It is not because reasons dont exist.)

Comment: I did search before posting this and didn't find the dup. I may repost about removing acceptance altogether, but I'd be amazed if it weren't met with the same "it's perfect the way it is--go away" circle jerk every honest suggestion for improvement gets.

Comment: @Lee What it is met with will depend entirely on your attitude and ability to conduct a civil discussion. If it is met with "go away", it is more likely that the blame rests on your approach. Your image of yourself as the only honest guy fighting against an army of people that want you to go away is incorrect, but if that's the view you must take to rationalize why others disagree with you then so be it. Maintaining respect for others' intelligence, reasonableness, and validity, is important, though.

Comment: I read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work very carefully, and while it describes the process in great detail, not a word of it *justifies* the process. If there are good reasons for the system, I have yet to hear one. The closest to an actual reason for the status quo I sometimes hear is that the current level of success of stackexchange justifies not changing it lightly. But compared with, say, Facebook, Google, and other sites notable for changing things constantly, our moderate success is perhaps not a laurel worth resting on.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker If none of the existing discussion made it clear I'm not sure how useful explaining it here will be either, and I suspect you're looking for a fight rather than an explanation anyways. So, it sounds like you're doomed to eternal frustration over not knowing why "accept" exists. That stinks!

Comment: I'm really not "looking for a fight", unless you consider rational argument a "fight". I simply proposed a change, and advocated for my position as any honest person would. I'm clearly outnumbered, and that's fine, but I am frustrated that I am outnumbered without having engaged in any actual argument.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Nothing is stopping you from posting a question here asking what "accept" is for. Pro-tip, from experience: Post it as a short, genuine question, without including statements or loaded/biased questions. List the resources you've read so far that didn't answer your question, and tag it as [tag:support], not [tag:discussion].